# Which part of speech is 'much' in "Don't think so much about the future!"

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Don't think so much about the future!

In this sentence, 'much' is an 'adverb' or a 'pronoun'?
I think the role of 'much' can vary with verbs, so it's difficult to determine what it is for a nonnative.

Comment: In your example it's a determinative functioning as an adjunct of degree in the clause. It's an adverb in, for example, "I feel much better", where it modifies "better".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that use, it's an adverb, modifying "think". 
See a similar adverb use at
[AHD "much" adverb 3](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=much)
and in other dictionaries.